# Sublime Text, getting configuration under version control

Tags: windows, linux, version-control, sublime-text-2

After using [vim](http://www.vim.org/) for the better part of a year I've decided to give [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) a whirl.

Using vim my `.vimrc` of course grew quite substantial since I constantly found small ways to modify it, I ended up putting my [.vim under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5103239/3287).

I've been using Sublime Text for a few weeks now, installing several plugins, and as I'm exploring plugins and configurations I get a blistering headache trying to keep my work machine (Windows) and my home machine (Linux) in sync.

So, how do I get my configuration back under (version) control?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way I've done it myself:

1. Install [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) or [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) on both systems. *In the following steps it will be assumed that you have installed Dropbox with default directory layout*.
2. Assuming you have the up-to-date settings on Linux, move there the `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages` directory to `~/Dropbox/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages` and create the following symlink:

   ```
   ln -s ~/Dropbox/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages
   ```
3. On Windows remove the `%UserProfile%\AppData\Sublime Text 2\Packages` directory and in place of it create a symlink pointing to `%UserProfile%\Dropbox\.config\sublime-text-2\Packages` by running:

   ```
   mklink /d "%UserProfile%\AppData\Sublime Text 2\Packages" %UserProfile%\Dropbox\.config\sublime-text-2\Packages
   ```

*Please note that the commands are only provided for reference and I haven't tested them.*

Comment: Warning: do not create git repositories in DropBox.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Firstly, what does it have to do with my answer and secondly why not?

Comment: The OP mentioned version control as well as sync. Placing a git repository in a DropBox folder results in corruption of the git database. Same for mercurial. It'll work well for a while, but if it updates as you're saving, it'll be left in an inconsistent and irrecoverable state.

Comment: I couldn't run mklink /d as a regular user, but mklink /j seems to have worked fine after I made sure that directory was *not read only*.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively) has a lot more information about possible git corruption with Dropbox. Most people seem to think it's worth the risk.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I've been using Dropbox+Git very heavily for a past year, switching between a dozen of systems and a lot of projects, and I can say that I haven't had a single bad experience with it. It's proven itself to be absolutely stable in that sense. So all the problems you've experienced with it have probably been fixed for at least a year now.